# General solution vs IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Suppose a $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has $n$ independent eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Then the general solution to $\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ is
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{x}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\mathbf{v}_ke^{\lambda_k t}
 \end{equation}
where $c_1,...,c_n$ are arbitrary constants.

In the case of an initial value problem with $\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}^0$, is there anything that can be said about the constants $c_1,...,c_n$ apart from the fact that they need to satisfy
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\mathbf{v}_k=\mathbf{x}^0
$$
My thinking is that, since the eigenvectors are not unique the multiples $c_k\mathbf{v}_k$ are also eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ for the same eigenvalues, thus nothing else can be said about those. Is this correct?

Comment: The first statement is not true. A $2\times 2$ matrix may have one eigenvector.

Comment: The one that starts with "Then the general solution".

Comment: If you fix the question, it will be fixed.